# What is the best practice to name a method that must either return saved result or resolve it?

Tags: java, naming

Consider the following java code:

```
public class Foo {
   
    private Bar bar;

    ....

    public Bar xxxBar() {
        if (this.bar == null) {
            //resolve bar
            this.bar = resolvedBar;
        }
        return this.bar;
    }
    ...
}
```

The idea of `xxxBar` method is to do resolving only once and save result. At the same time I want to show in API, that calling this method multiple times won't lead to any performance problems.
What is the best way to name it? For now I use `getOrResolveBar` but I am not sure, that it is a common way.

Comment: One note: you you probably `synchronize` the method, or some part therein.

Comment: @user949300 That is not so important for this question. There are a lot of examples when one object is created and used only within one method scope {}.

Comment: If you have a BarService you can have a BarServiceLocator. See https://stackify.com/service-locator-pattern/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known as [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)), [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), or [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.). The [singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is an example of this practice.

However, the best naming practice is to simply give the method a meaningful descriptive name based on what the method does. Not how it does it. In a good design the caching is something you don't have to think about as you work with the rest of the code. This simplifies the code base and gives you the freedom to stop caching if you later decide it's not needed without having to refactor an outdated name everywhere you spread it.

So I don't need xxx to tell me about the caching. You could just call it bar. Assuming bar is a meaningful name in your domain.

Answer (score 1):

When you write a getter, it is assumed that it can be called repeatedly without any extra expense. Maybe a little expense, if you do a billion calls it will cost time, but not something the caller normally worries about.

And that is the case here: I can call xxxBar as often as I like without any penalty. The penalty for the first call is clearly unavoidable, and nothing the caller can do anything about - as a caller I may be able to avoid call #2 to #1,000,000,000 but I can't avoid the first call.

Call your method getBar. If it didn't cache *and* resolvedBar was more expensive than I expect from a getter, then you should pick another name.